# CSS Titles Not Centered

Tags: css

I added letter spacing for the word "OUTDOOR" and the words "IS WHERE LIFE HAPPENS", and they're just a bit uneven as you can see below. I tried to add padding but that didn't work how do I fix this? [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23xOl.png)

```
<body>

    <header class="header">

        <div class="header__logo-box">

            <img src="img/logo-white.png" alt="logo" class="header__logo">

        </div><!-- .logo-box --->

        <div class="header__text-box">

            <h1 class="heading-primary">

                <span class="heading-primary--main">OUTDOORS</span>
                <span class="heading-primary--sub">IS WHERE LIFE HAPPENS</span>

            </h1>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn--white btn--animate"><span>DISCOVER OUR TOURS</span> </a>

        </div><!-- .text-box -->

    </header><!-- .header -->

</body>



html{
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

.header__text-box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

h1.heading-primary{
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 6rem;
}

.heading-primary--main{
    display: block;
    font-size: 6rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 3.5rem;
    animation: moveInLeft 1s;
}

.heading-primary--sub{
    display: block;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1.75rem;
    animation: moveInRight 1s;
}
```

The website in the image was made in [Advanced CSS and SASS](https://www.udemy.com/advanced-css-and-sass/learn/v4/overview) course on udemy. Credit to Jonas Schmedtmann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in .heading-primary--main :

```css
letter-spacing: 3.5rem;
text-indent: 3.5rem;
```

and in .heading-primary--sub :

```css
letter-spacing: 1.6rem;
text-indent: 1.6rem;
```

Comment: Your snippets are useless.

Comment: sorry i am new to stackoverflow how should i write response ? without snippet ?

Comment: In order for your snippet to show anything, you must enter both HTML and CSS code. What you've done, is create two snippets with no HTML and only half the CSS each.

Comment: yes i mean that he should add those snippets in the class of his css file
"add in .heading-primary--sub"